# Disabling Controls(Button) outside the gridview trigger with Row Editing Event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to disable a control(button) but it's outside the grideview triggered with gridview's row editing events.

```
Protected Sub gdvCountryList_RowEditing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gdvCountryList.RowEditing

    Try

        BtnSaveCountry.Enabled = False

        gdvCountryList.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        SetCountryTable()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw ex

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. You always have access to controls that are on the page outside the GridView, even in the RowEditing method. I assume you want to disable `BtnSaveCountry`, but where on the page is it located?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to disable the BtnSaveCountry using the gridview's RowEditng event. Button's location is in the same page, just it's not within the gridview (top).

Comment: Can you show the aspx code? Because you always have access to controls that are outside the GridView.